# Warning: Function must be extern error in C

Tags: c, assembly

I am following along a tutorial for C programming in 6502 Assembly and am having a great deal of difficulty on the 3rd step. When compiling my code in the command line, i get these errors:

test4.c(8): Error: '{' expected

test4.c(9): Warning: Function must be extern

test4.c(9): Error: ';' expected

test4.c(13): Error: '}' expected

I am using a program to compile .c files made in code::blocks to .nes files. The current tutorial is having me also make .s assembly file when compiling in the cl65 command line in Windows from the program that is compiling it. Here is the link to the tutorial page i am on: 
https://helloacm.com/tutorial-3-c-programming-in-6502-using-assembly/

I have tried many different combinations of code that i can think of to try and get rid of a least some of the problems, but alas to no avail. I am an amateur in C, usually use C++ but i cannot and still trying to figure this out. I was not able to find the "Function must be extern" error anywhere with a quick google search either. Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Here is how i wrote the code in code::blocks:

```
void main()
{
    asm("nop");
}

void testasm()

void main()
{
    while(1) {
    testasm(); // call the assembled function
}
}
```

Also, had a really difficult time following along on this particular tutorial part.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated on diagnosing the problem!

Comment: You can't have 2 `main()` functions! Also a function prototype has to end with `;` like `void testasm();`

Comment: In addition to the two main() functions, you are missing a semicolon after testasm().

Comment: Please try to always indent the code for each code block, for readability and clarity.

Comment: @Rizier123 had gotten rid of the 1st main function before and it changed nothing with the error codes, so i left it in when i was pasting my code in just for reference.

I added the ; to testasm and also extern in front of void testasm and everything was fixed.

I will note that for future posts. Sorry for the bad post, still new to posting on this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're after?

```
void testasm()
{
    asm("nop");
}

void main()
{
    while(1) {
        testasm(); // call the assembled function
    }
}
```

Your code had two `main()` functions, and a prototype `void testasm()` with no terminating semicolon.

---

Alternatively, if `testasm` is written in assembly, your code should look like this (removing the extra `main` function):

```
extern void testasm();    // `extern` not specifically required, but may be for
                          // your particular compiler

void main()
{
    while(1) {
        testasm(); // call the assembled function
    }
}
```

You need to be much more careful writing code.

Comment: Thank you, the "extern void testasm();" worked. I had not encountered/heard of extern void ever. I had gotten rid of the 1st main function before and it changed nothing with the error codes, so i left it in when i was pasting my code in just for reference.

Comment: Perhaps you were just missing the semicolon `;`? Either way, the `extern` says "hey, this thing exists, but in another file (compilation unit)"